# Why is jQuery Validation adding noValidate attribute?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm currently using:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootStrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

with validation such as:

```
j$('.delValidate').each(function(){

j$(this).validate({
    rules:{
        delivery_Method:{
            required: true
        }
    },
    message:{
        delivery_Method:{
            required: true
        }
    }
});

});

    j$('.validateUser').each(function(){
        j$(this).validate({
            rules:{
                f_Name:{
                    required: true
                },
                l_Name:{
                    required: true  
                },
                username:{
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 6
                },
                password: {
                    validChars: true,
                    noSpace: true,
                    minlength: 6,
                    skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]
                },
                confPass: {
                    equalTo: "#password",
                    skip_or_fill_minimum: [3,".pw"]
                }           
            }
        });
    });
```

HTML snippet:

```
<form class="form-horizontal delValidate" action="#" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="formIdentifier" value="addDel" />
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="delivery_Method" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter new method" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2">
        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-default btn-block">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

But when I go to my page, My form is rendered with the attribute noValidate and therefore I can insert null/empty values into the database. What is the reasoning for this? 
Does the form have to be set up in a particular way? 
Does jQuery validation pick up something is wrong and therefore doesn't work?
My dirty work around is using:

```
j$(this).removeAttr('novalidate');
```

Comment: Your code is working fine:  http://jsfiddle.net/tv7Bz/

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `novalidate` attribute simply tells the browser to disable the built-in HTML5 validation, or ignore any HTML5 validation attributes you may have used.

The jQuery Validate plugin dynamically adds the `novalidate` attribute because, by installing it, you've decided to let the plugin handle validation *instead* of HTML5.

Neither of those two methods, JavaScript (jQuery) or HTML5, are good enough for protecting your database.  **You should always have some kind of server-side validation in place for when client-side validation fails, is disabled, or bypassed by the user/browser.**

**Quote OP:**

> *" My form is rendered with the attribute noValidate and therefore I can insert null/empty values into the database."*

Sounds like something is very wrong with the way you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, and the `novalidate` attribute is not the root cause.

If it's critical that you cannot enter `null` data, you'll need data validation code on the server side to prevent this.  **You must never rely on client-side code to protect the database since all client-side code can be easily bypassed.**

> *"What is the reasoning for this?"*

As explained above.  This is normal and desired.  The plugin simply uses `novalidate` to take over client side validation from the browser (HTML5).

If you have no HTML5 validation attributes, then the `novalidate` attribute, or lack of `novalidate` attribute, does absolutely nothing.  In other words, it only toggles the HTML5 validation *if you use HTML5 validation attributes*.

> *"Does the form have to be set up in a particular way?"*

Yes.  But we cannot see your markup to tell where you went wrong.

> *"My dirty work around is using: `.removeAttr('novalidate')`"*

This is not smart, or completely superfluous, depending on your markup.  Effectively, you are potentially allowing HTML5 validation to occur simultaneously with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Pick one or the other for client-side validation.

---

**EDIT**:

The OP has since added some HTML markup to the question.

The jQuery Validate plugin is working exactly as expected:  http://jsfiddle.net/tv7Bz/

Comment: Great explanation @Sparky.
I have edited my question and popped some HTML in, the noValidate makes a lot more sense to me now! I browsed through other posts but couldn't get a detailed explanation such as this. 
Heads up, I do have server side validation in place.

Comment: @AkiraDawson, I put your code into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tv7Bz/) and it works fine. There must be something else you're not showing us.